# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck at LightDM login screen

Tags: lightdm, 16.04

So I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday. Today I wanted to login to the computer and suddenly it doesn't log me in anymore. I can enter my password, but when I hit return to log in the screen goes black for a second and I end up right back in the login screen again. Does someone know what could be the issue?

Comment: You have by any chance a Nvidia GPU ?

Comment: @Videonauth  do have an NVIDIA GPU yes. And now I think of it, I did install the propriatary drivers as the last thing I did before this happened

Comment: Then have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) maybe this will solve your sorrows.

Comment: It happend with me too once I installed the nvidia driver.Then I realised its because of the driver.So, what I did is that I went to additional drivers and then rather choose xorg that fixed my problem.

Comment: @Videonauth Sorry for the late reaction, but that solved my problem :) Running the drivers from the PPA for now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I tried to switch to proprietary graphics driver from settings.
By default x server was in charge. Provided that you got a similar issue here, you can try to uninstall the driver.

In my case, I had Nvidia, so I went to `tty1` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>,
then enter login and password,
and use `purge` to uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo reboot
```